# How to scroll to element useScroll framer motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, framer-motion, scrollto

The scroll is never stay on the top of the element, it always scroll or more pixels than need or less
What's wrong?
I tried react-observers, event listeners, etc. nothing helps
PLEASE SOMEONE HELPPPP
I cant find even some solution for this in whole internet, I could use just scroll snap, but it needs only to a few blocks, that have 100vh height and margin 20px between each other. Also their container has width: calc(1920px - 720px);
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative; so i can just use scroll snap

```
const FranchisePage = () => {
    const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState(0)

    const sections = [
        useRef(null),
        useRef(null),
        useRef(null),
        useRef(null),
        useRef(null),
    ]

    const whyUsVisible = useInView(sections[0], {
        margin: "-20% 0px -80% 0px"
    })

    const propositionVisible = useInView(sections[1])

    const cyberSportVisible = useInView(sections[2])

    const infrastructureVisible = useInView(sections[3])

    const newFormatVisible = useInView(sections[4])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!(whyUsVisible || propositionVisible || cyberSportVisible || infrastructureVisible || newFormatVisible)) {
            setCurrentSection(-1)
        }

        console.log(currentSection)

        if (whyUsVisible && currentSection !== 0) {
            console.log(sections[0].current.getBoundingClientRect())
            window.scrollTo({
                top: sections[0].current.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY,
                behavior: "smooth"
            })
            setTimeout(() => setCurrentSection(0), 200)
        } else if (propositionVisible && currentSection !== 1) {
            window.scrollTo({
                top: sections[1].current.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY,
                behavior: "smooth"
            })
            setTimeout(() => setCurrentSection(1), 200)
        } else if (cyberSportVisible && currentSection !== 2) {
            window.scrollTo({
                top: sections[2].current.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY,
                behavior: "smooth"
            })
            setTimeout(() => setCurrentSection(2), 200)
        } else if (infrastructureVisible && currentSection !== 3) {
            window.scrollTo({
                top: sections[3].current.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY,
                behavior: "smooth"
            })
            setTimeout(() => setCurrentSection(3), 200)
        } else if (newFormatVisible && currentSection !== 4) {
            console.log(sections[4].current.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY)
            window.scrollTo({
                top: sections[4].current.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY,
                behavior: "smooth"
            })
            setTimeout(() => setCurrentSection(4), 200)
        }
    }, [whyUsVisible, propositionVisible, cyberSportVisible, infrastructureVisible, newFormatVisible]);

    return (
        <div className="franchise">
            <Container>
                <FranchiseCover/>
                <VideoCarousel/>
                <Philosophy/>
                <WhyUs ref={sections[0]}/>
                <Proposition ref={sections[1]}/>
                <CyberSport ref={sections[2]}/>
                <Infrastructure ref={sections[3]}/>
                <NewFormat ref={sections[4]}/>
                <YellowSection/>
                <OurExperience/>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FranchisePage;
```

I spent so many attempts and hours on this.